# Automatically appending --exclude-dir=xxxx (multiple dirs) to grep bash command?

Tags: linux, bash, profile

I'd like to automatically exclude several 3rd party library folders so I don't have to retype it every time.  How would one accomplish such a task?

Answer (score 4):

You can either create an alias

```
alias grep='grep --exclude-dir=xxxx'
```

that you would add to your `.bashrc`, or setup an environment variable

```
export  GREP_OPTIONS='--exclude-dir=xxxx'
```

that you would add to your `.bash_profile`.

Note that aliases only work at the beginning of a command line (start of line, or after a pipe, or an opening parenthese, etc.) Consequently, `... | xargs grep ...`, for instance, won't use the alias. By contrast, the env variable will be honored, which can have its downsides as mentioned below.

Comment: It should be added that, while extremely handy, one should use GREP_OPTIONS with great care, because all shell scripts run from the command line inherit it, and probably don't care to unset it. I have seen people breaking scripts by adding `-n` to GREP_OPTIONS, which changes the output of grep.

Comment: I'd give you the answer, but it doesn't work for me when putting it in my ~/.bash_aliases file, which is included as such:

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

Answer (score 3):

You can alias grep to always include the parameter. On your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias grep="grep --exclude-dir=xxxx"
```